# Calculating expectation function and covariance function

Tags: self-study, covariance, stochastic-processes

> Let $E_n(t)$ denote the empirical cdf based on iid uniform $u[0,1]$ random variables $U_1,...,U_n.$ The corresponding uniform empirical process $(e_n(t),0\leq t\leq 1)$ is given by $$e_n(t)=\sqrt{n}(E_n(t)-t)$$
>
> Calculate the expectation function and the covariance function of this process.

My question: Is $E_n(t)$ the sum of the cdfs of random variables $U_1,..,U_n$ or does the subscript $n$ mean that it is the cdf generated by $n$ random variables? Also, how come $E_n$ depends on $t$?

Comment: Normally, "cdf" refers to "cumulative distribution function": it is a *function* and to evaluate it you must supply a real argument, here called "$t$".  If you're confused about what an *empirical* cdf might be, then a glance at some of our [related posts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ecdf+definition) might be of immediate help.

Comment: For any given $t \in [0,1]$, the value of the _empirical cdf_ is a _discrete_ random variable taking on values $0, \frac 1n, \frac 2n, \cdots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1$ with (unequal) probabilities. So, you need to figure these probabilities and then find the expected value of the stochastic process at time $t$.

Comment: Suggestion: look up the definition of "empirical cdf".

Comment: Crossposted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1065492